# Ember js: Setting a property only once (in an observer) throws Deprecation Warning You modified X twice in a single render

Tags: ember.js

I am running into quite some peculiar behavior. The thing is I understand the deprecation warning, however, it should not be happening as an 'observes', IMHO, does not use a getter, so, setting a property should not cause the deprecation.

I am using Ember 2.2.0 and Ember-Cli 1.13.8. Everything is structured in Components and, if need be, Services (global singletons). Here's a simplified version of my code. I should maybe make a JSFiddle and try to reproduce it, but I figured someone might spot the error directly.

Parent component template:

```
{{my-component model=service.currentModel changed=changed}}
```

my-component.js:

```
watchChanged: function() {
    this.set('model', this.get('some_internal_value')); //this throws deprecation, even though it should not
    this.get('parentView').send('resetChanged'); // reset changed in the parent
}.observes('changed', 'some_internal_value')
```

I went with the debugger and watchChanged is called EXACTLY ONCE, in spite of this fact, the deprecation warning is thrown. The code works perfectly, save for the deprecation warning. Any ideas?

My workaround is to do the set as a task in the 'afterRender' queue, but this isn't a solution for the issues that I am experiencing.

What is the "ember-way" in this case? Is it a bug or a lack of understanding on my side?

Edit: cross-posted it [here](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/setting-a-property-only-once-in-an-observer-throws-deprecation-warning-you-modified-x-twice-in-a-single-render/9216).

Edit x1: There are no didInsertElement/willInsertElement hooks implemented in the parent, nor in the child. I assume that the service querying is somehow causing it... but I do not have enough experience with services to say for sure.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see enough of the `{{my-component}}` code to say for sure, but my guess is that either `changed` or `some_internal_value`, or one of their dependencies, are being updated as part of a rendering lifecycle hook. Commonly this is `willRender` or `didInsertElement`. Check for those in your component, try commenting them out temporarily to test.

Sometimes an `afterRender` is necessary, but you should definitely avoid it as much as possible.

Comment: There is no didInsertElement/willInsertElement. I assume it has something to do with the service querying... The model is queried from the service. Any and all feedback is appreciated.

Comment: I don't have an init() either. I am going to assume that it happens as a consequence of the service injection.... maybe someone else can shed some light on the issue.

Comment: There really isn't much that anyone can discern from your code example. Perhaps you could make an ember-twiddle that demonstrates your problem? Or share the full contents of the `my-component.js` file. I'm happy to try to help, but I can't do any more with what you've provided. 

I found dozens of these errors when upgrading my app to 2.x and every single one was related updating a property in `didInsertElement` or `willRender`. `didInitAttrs` and `init` are both safe.

Comment: The only other thought I had, was if you're calling `set` inside of a computed property that is really a `get` operation. The template will cause many `get`s to fire during render and if one of those `get`s is resulting in a `set` that could be your cause.

Comment: The observes function body is not a getter, or? The exception is thrown EXACTLY at the line where I marked it. Even though the observer runs only once!

I will try to make a twiddle and reproduce the issue. Thanks for your feedback thus far.